# Login via curl to webmail

Tags: php, curl

I wanna login to my [university webmail](http://sabamail.kntu.ac.ir:3000/WorldClient.dll?View=Main) page by curllib.

I program following code to do that:

```
$url = 'http://eetd.kntu.ac.ir/mda2.asp';
$reffer = 'http://sabamail.kntu.ac.ir:3000/WorldClient.dll?View=Main';
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$cookie_file_path = "/var/www/cookie.txt";
$post_fields = 'dom=ee.kntu.ac.ir&usr=hoseini&password=*****';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,$reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

but it will redirect to [1](http://sabamail.kntu.ac.ir:3000/WorldClient.dll?View=Main) again with out showing your password is wrong!
where is problem?

Comment: Problem: your password is wrong!

Comment: @genesisφ I use true password,but I replace it here by star:D and If my password is wrong,it should print it.

Comment: You can't trust that the error response is accurate. Any of your details could be wrong and it could have the same result. It's actually better not to reveal specifically the password is wrong. Confirm your params, username, password, cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

site says:

```
<input type="password" name="pd" size="18">
```

you set:

```
$post_fields = 'dom=ee.kntu.ac.ir&usr=hoseini&password=*****';
```

change password to pd

Answer (score 3):

If you actually examine the source code of the login page, you will find the password element is named `pd` and not `password`.

Therefore you need to change this:

```
$post_fields = 'dom=ee.kntu.ac.ir&usr=hoseini&password=*****';
```

...to this:

```
$post_fields = 'dom=ee.kntu.ac.ir&usr=hoseini&pd=*****';
```

This may not be the only issue, but it is certainly an issue.

Comment: damn was too slow, stucked with the captchar :D